# lm() linear model - attributes

Tags: r, lm

So I get a bit confused by the lm()-command. I tried it with `lm(x~y, mydata)` and `lm(y~x, mydata)` and I got different output.
So is that just which variable to use as x and which one to use as y? I'm sorry to ask such a noob question but I am not sure and I coulnd't find anything explaining the parameters of that command!

Comment: You're right that they are different. The choice of whether to model `x` on `y` (`x~y`) or `y` on `x` (`y~x`) is a statistical one, not a programming question. What is your data?

Comment: When you do not know how to use a function in R use `?` to get help on the function. For instance `?lm` shows the `lm` help page. Other useful commands are `??` which looks for a term in the help (e.g. `??regression`) and `RSiteSearch("something")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answers can be found on the help page for the function. In the `Details` section we have:

`A typical model has the form response ~ terms where response is the (numeric) response vector and terms is a series of terms which specifies a linear predictor for response.`

There are more details (also linked to from the `lm` help page to `formula`. In the details sections for `formula`, we have:

`The ~ operator is basic in the formation of such models. An expression of the form y ~ model is interpreted as a specification that the response y is modelled by a linear predictor specified symbolically by model.`

So to summarize, you define your model in symbolic terms where the LHS is your response variable, and the RHS are your predictor variable(s). You get different answers because in one model, `y` is your response variable and the other is `x`.

If you weren't aware, you can access the help page for nearly all functions with `?` at the command line, i.e. `?lm` or `?formula`.

Comment: See also [Section 11.1: Defining statistical models; formulae](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Formulae-for-statistical-models) in an Introduction to R.

Comment: great! thanks to everyone! didn't know how to get help in R for a particular command! that helps also a lot!!

Comment: @cups - also check out rseek.org for another good resource. R can certainly have a steep initial learning curve, but you'll pick it up quickly!